# como adjuntar archivos en android api 28 android studio para enviar por email

Tags: android, studio

Hola espero que me ayuden en este pequeño problema tengo una aplicación  en el cual lleno un formulario y me genera un archivo PDF, para despues enviarlo por medio de la app de gmail, me funciona perfecto en android 7 pero lo migre a android 9 y ya no me funciona, lo unico que no logro hacer es adjuntar el archivo pdf, investigando me tope que el codigo para obtener el path esta obsoleto, pero no se cual es el mas actualizado para reemplasarlo, espero que me ayuden de antemano muchas gracias, adjunto el codigo para que vean lo que tengo. Marco en negritas el codigo que me da conflicto

public class Enviar_pdf extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button Nuevo, Enviar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enviar_pdf);
    Nuevo  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Norden);
    Nuevo.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick20);
    Enviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonSendFeedback);

    Nuevo.setEnabled(false);


    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonSendFeedback)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String to = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTo)).getText().toString();
            String sub = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSubject)).getText().toString();
            String cc = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.ccto)).getText().toString();


            **Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Trinity/PDF Files/", "Orden de servicio RSI.pdf"));**

            Intent mail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{to});
            mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{cc , "prueba@gmail.com"});
            mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, sub);
            mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "orden de servicio" );
            mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            mail.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mail, "Enviar email por:"));

            Nuevo.setEnabled(true);
            Enviar.setEnabled(false);



        }
    });
}





Button.OnClickListener onButtonClick20 = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent Nuevo = new Intent(Enviar_pdf.this, Menucapturardatos.class);
        startActivity(Nuevo);
        finishAffinity();
    }
};

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago a través de FileProvider, para ésto debes declararlo en el manifest:

```
 <provider
  android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
  android:authorities="${filesAuthority}"
  android:exported="false"
  android:grantUriPermissions="true">
   <meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths_app" />
 </provider>
```

Dónde el filestAuthority es una constante declarada en el build gradle del módulo de la app.  Lo declaro aquí para que también se pueda acceder desde el código programáticamente:

```
defaultConfig {
 def filesAuthorityValue = applicationId + ".fileProvider"
 manifestPlaceholders = [filesAuthority: filesAuthorityValue]
 buildConfigField("String", "FILES_AUTHORITY", "\"${filesAuthorityValue}\"")
}
```

Y por último debes crear en res/ un paquete xml -> res/xml y un fichero xml, por ejemplo, provider-paths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Después de la configuración, la uri para el intent es:

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(yourContext, "com.your.project.root.fileProvider", yourPdfFile)
```